# For each of the following set expressions, say what set the expression denotes. In other words if the se....

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

For each of the following set expressions, say what set the expression denotes. In other words if the set is finite, give an explicit listing of its elements.. **Assume A = {2,3,4}**

**a) {x:x ∈ Z, -3.5 < x < 3.5}∩ {y:y ∈ Z, 2|y}**

**b) {x:x ∈ P(A), |x| = 2}**

So for **a)** would I put something like... **x such that x is a element of all integers between -3.5 and 3.5 AND y such that y is a element of all integers,** but I don;t know how to interpret the **|** symbol. What does that mean? Am I going about this the correct way? And I have no idea how to do **b)**

Comment: It means "divides". $2|y$ means $y$ is even.

Comment: For **b)**, the required set is the set of *subsets* of $A$ (because $x \in \mathcal P(A)$ means that $x$ is a member of the *power-set* of $A$, i.e. the set of all subsets of $A$) such that they have two elements (because $|x|$ for a set $x$ means its "cardinality", i.e. the number of its elements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**b)**

$|x|$ is the *cardinality* of $x$ i.e the number of elements.

as $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{\emptyset,\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\},\{2,3,4\}\}$

the set must contain of the three elements of $\mathcal{P}$ having cardinality $2$, i.e the entire set is:

$\{x : x \in \mathcal{P}(A), |x| = 2\} = \{\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}\}$